# How to find the most popular Genre

Tags: c#

I have a txt. file of films with their name, release year, genre, studio, director, main actor, and earnings. It's all in a list, and I need to find the most popular genre among the films on the list

```
void FindTheMostPopularGenre(List<FilmName> FilmList)
        {
            var groupsWithCounts = from s in FilmList
                                   group s by s into g
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       Item = g.Key,
                                       Count = g.Count()
                                   };

            var groupsSorted = groupsWithCounts.OrderByDescending(g => g.Count);
            string mostFrequest = groupsSorted.First().Item;

        }
```

I tried using this function, but It gives me this error

Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'L3_9.FilmName' to 'string'

How can I fix this code, or should I be using a different approach here?

Comment: What type is `FilmName`, probably not a string! (Hint)

Comment: Its a List, and I read data to it using ```FilmName filmName = new FilmName(name,year,genre,studio,director,mainactor,earning);
                    FilmList.Add(filmName);```

Comment: No, it's not a list - it's the type of list. And it's not a string. Change `string` to `var` in the last line of your code and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the property name you want to group by:

```
void FindTheMostPopularGenre(List<FilmName> FilmList)
    {
        var groupsWithCounts = from s in FilmList
                               group s by s.Genre into g // <<<
                               select new
                               {
                                   Item = g.Key,
                                   Count = g.Count()
                               };

        var groupsSorted = groupsWithCounts.OrderByDescending(g => g.Count);
        string mostFrequest = groupsSorted.First().Item;

    }
```